# Mouse coordinates causing window to resize with mpl_scatter_density

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a custom toolbar in Matplolib.
For it to work, I had to set `plot.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'`
Which has the side effect to increase the mouse coordinates font size.

The problem occurs in combination with mpl_scatter_density. These plots add an extra row to the mouse coordinates frame for the density value. Coordinates look like:

```
x=2.3535 y=4.565
[2.56] <--- extra row with density value
```

Since the coordinates appear only when the mouse is within the plot limits, this extra row increases the toolbar height and causes the entire window to erratically resize when moving the mouse in and out of the plot which is very annoying.

Code used: (but without the custom toolbar which is too big to paste here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import mpl_scatter_density # adds projection='scatter_density'
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

# "Viridis-like" colormap with white background
white_viridis = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('white_viridis', [
    (0, '#ffffff'),
    (1e-20, '#440053'),
    (0.2, '#404388'),
    (0.4, '#2a788e'),
    (0.6, '#21a784'),
    (0.8, '#78d151'),
    (1, '#fde624'),
], N=256)


# Fake data for testing
x = np.random.normal(size=100000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=100000)

fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='scatter_density')
density = ax.scatter_density(x, y, cmap=white_viridis)
fig.colorbar(density, label='Number of points per pixel')

plot.show()
```

My idea to solve the problem was either to set a smaller font size with `plot.rcParams['font.size']` (which works well when setting it manually within VScode debugger but does not work for some reason when executing the script normally !) OR to remove the density value completely.

However, `ax.format_coord` modifies only the format of the first row of mouse coordinates. I can't seem to find how to modify the density value format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format_coord` only formats the x and y representation. To format the data representation, use [`format_cursor_data`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_cursor_data.html):

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import mpl_scatter_density  # adds projection='scatter_density'
import numpy as np

# Fake data for testing
x = np.random.normal(size=100000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=100000)

fig = plot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="scatter_density")
density = ax.scatter_density(x, y)

# replace existing data representation with empty one
density.format_cursor_data = lambda _: ""

fig.colorbar(density, label="Number of points per pixel")

plot.show()
```

Comment: Thank you Christian! This is working. I actually tried it but with 'ax.format_cursor_data' which was not doing anything.